# How to set a key with value along with expiry using Java JedisCluster?

Tags: java, jedis

I am using JedisCluster, and I need to set a key with 1-hour expiry, now I am doing something like

```
    getJedisCluster().set(key,value);
    getJedisCluster().expire(key, 60 * 60);
```

But I hope I can using a single command to reduce the round trip to send commands

With Redis cli , I can write this:

```
set key value ex 3600
```

But in JedisCluster, I can only find a interface:

```
 public String set(final String key, final String value, final String nxxx, final String expx, final long time) {
```

which means I either should use setex or setnx.

But I hope my set command applies both to update or insert.

How can I do this?

Ps: Jedis-Client's version is  2.9.0

Comment: Im not sure about this. But can you tried `set(final String key, final String value, final SetParams params)` ? As `SetParams` can hold `secondsToExpire ` and `millisecondsToExpire `.

Comment: @Zico  Which version do you use, I can't find this method in class JedisCluster

Comment: Just explored the `JedisCluster` [here](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/JedisCluster.java) is the source file.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jedis client version 2.9.1

```
jedis.setex(sid, 86400,String.valueOf(version));
```

In the latest versions, we have something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use setex method directly. It does exactly this

```
 set key value ex 3600
```